# mysql jdbc driver and java project

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, crud

When I try to make crud operation like delete or insert, for the first time when I click on the button, I get an error of connection (the error message is from the connection function) :

```
public static void ConnexionDB(String sql){
            Statement stmt = null;
            try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jeux?user=root&password=root");
        stmt = (Statement) connect.createStatement();
       stmt.execute(sql);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("connection error");
            }
        }
```

but when I click one time more on the button the operation is successful and I connect to the DB without error message.
I can't find the problem!

Comment: Change `System.out.println("connection error");` to `e.printStackTrace();` it will provide you and use with much more useful information

Comment: suppose the issue may be with the button you call to make the connection. Share the code you that include the button.